# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\le\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let (a$_n$) and (b$_n$) be convergent sequences. Prove the following statement:

If there is  a number $N$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ so that a$_n$ $\le$ b$_n$ applies for all n $\ge$ $N$ follows: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}$ a$_n$ $\le$ $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}$  b$_n$.

My thoughts: I'm not sure how I can prove this statement. I know that $a_n \le b_n$ and by the definition we have that  $\displaystyle a= \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and $b =\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$.

Doesn't that already prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\le \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$?

I do not think that my thoughts are correct and I don't have much time left to solve this task. I would really appreciate any hints that would lead me to the right direction.

$EDIT:$ I had some ideas on how to approach this task and im curious on what you guys think about it.

Proof by contradiction: Let $\epsilon$ > 0 be arbitrary. According to the definition of the convergence $\exists$ $N_1$ $\land$ $N_2$ $\forall$ $\epsilon$ > 0.

My assumption now is that: $\exists$ $N_1$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall$ n $\geq$ $N$: $N_1$ + $\epsilon$ > b$_n$. But since I have a$_n$ $\leq$ b$_n$ it follows that $\forall$ n $\leq$ $N$: $N_2$ + $\epsilon$ > a$_n$. It must follow that $N_1$ < $N_2$ which implies that  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\le\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$.

I don't think that works because $b_n$ > $\epsilon$ for example is in the realm of possibility right?

I also had another idea which is the following: Let $\epsilon$ := a - b. **Idea**: $|a_n - a |$ < a - b $\land$ $|b_n - b |$ < a - b. $|a_n - a |$ $\geq$ 0 
 $\Rightarrow$ $a_n$ - a < a - b $\Leftrightarrow$ $a_n$ $\leq$ a - b + a = $a_n$ $\leq$ b.

$|b_n - b |$ < a - b. Assume: $|b_n - b |$ $\geq$ 0 $\Rightarrow$ $b_n$ - b < a - b $\Leftrightarrow$ $b_n$ < a - b + b $\Rightarrow$ $b_n$ < a.

This doesn't really work does it? Where did I go wrong and what else could I try?

Comment: "I don't have much time left to solve this task" seems suspicious.

Comment: How? Take a quick look at my other questions and then come back with your false accusations. Just reread the last sentence of my question.

Comment: @KeJie I didn't accuse you of anything. You accused yourself.

Comment: For all $\epsilon>0$, there is $N_1$ such that for all $n>N$ $b_n<\lim_n b_n+\epsilon$. Therefore, for $n>\max(N_1,N)$ you have $a_n\leq b_n<\lim_n b_n+\epsilon$. If $\lim_n a_n > \lim_n b_n+\epsilon$, then there would be $N_2$, such that for $n>N_2$ $a_n>\lim_n b_n+\epsilon$.  Therefore $\lim_n a_n\leq \lim_n b_n+\epsilon$. Since this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, it follows that $\lim_n a_n\leq \lim_n b_n$.

Comment: @elmer Thank you! I really appreciate that.

Comment: No problem. By the way, the medicine against those "suspicious" in this site is just ignore them, and keep on doing math.

Comment: @KennyLau You did not explained how my questions is "suspicious" neither have you contributed something useful to the initial question.

Comment: KeJie, it seems a number of users have the same reservation as KennyLau

Comment: @amWhy Where did I asked for other users to solve this task for me? I asked politely for $hints$. I recommend you to look through my other questions and then you will realise that I have never violated any of the rules on this site. Just because some people are sharing the same view doesn't mean theyre right. Just look at all the passive agressive downvotes I am receiving for this one question. In fact I don't have much time left to solve this task and that's why I came here to ask for advice since I have no group partner or anything.

Comment: I read a couple of your answers, KeJie, and one of them was pretty poor, and inappropriate, because it was too broad.  You wanted confirmation on two answers you wrote up, and help with two questions on which you did nothing, all in one post.  It doesn't help when you address sincere questions and concerns with passive aggressive comments. Chill.  You'll get the hang of it, but please don't come here with an attitude.  That will just alienate users who have devoted an enormous amount of time volunteering with answers, and working to improve this site overall.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with you @KeJie. I don't think that it's necessarily a bad thing for homework to motivate a question (homework motivates plenty of genuine inquiry), and you haven't asked anyone to do yours. It saddens me slightly to see how many people will refuse to help on the *suspicion* that such answers will help you with your homework.

Comment: The two I read, of your earlier questions were not what I'd consider good questions.  One was too broad, wanting confirmation on to of your solutions, and wanting solutions to two other questions, all in one post.  So I already did what you suggested, prior to posting.  I'm not worried about you asking future questions, because you're

Comment: @Theo  Clearly you don't get it:  homework questions are acceptable, provided the OP shows effort or motivation or sufficient other context.  Not merely a *problem statement "question"* essentially copy and pasted from an assignment.  I don't think this post is a problem statement question only, as the asker clearly expressed some input.  Please read the help section (click on ? sitting on the top black bar, to the right of the page), and click on FAQ on "Asking" to learn more.

Comment: @amWhy I asked politely for hints and there is nothing wrong about that. I have seen a lot of similar questions (difference is that most of these questions  haven't received any downvotes). And why is it bad to ask for confirmation when there are virtually no other persons I can ask?

Comment: @KeJlie In case you missed it in the post immediately above (to Theo), I do give you credit.  But you can not ask four separate question in one post.  I think it would have been fine to post one question about the 2 answers you were seeking confirmation on, and then a separate question addressing the two you were stuck on.  It's asking a lot from a user to address 4 separate issues, answer 4 questions, in one answer post.  In any case, KeJie, I think you'll be fine here, but I think you need to rethink some of your expectations and taking offense at users merely trying to keep quality on MSE.

Comment: I agree with Theo. *Hint:* To avoid such *suspicion*, KeJie, you should avoid saying something like "I've to solve this before tomorrow" or "this is an assignment" or something that's not directly related to the question **itself**, purely. Those words give no further info. to your desired answer. This is not a rule, but an advice. To be fair, I see OP's at least put some efforts on this question.

Comment: @am Why I do not have any high exspectations since I still have to solve these questions on my own in the end of the day. All im hoping for are some hints that could give me some idea on how to approach certain tasks. As for the question of mine you are mentioning I admit that it was not the best way to adress 4 different questions at once and I will keep that in mind for the future. I still don't think that the downvotes are justified and in the end it's only a disappointing outcome for me.

Comment: @poyea Thanks I will keep that in mind for possible future questions.

Comment: poyea: yet another account, have we?

Comment: In truth, KeJie, you should never try to "fool" people by not honestly disclosing something.  I am okay with this question.  But please don't do what @poyea suggests, trying to withhold information.  There is nothing to hide, when you, as you did here, show some effort and/or thinking about the problem.  Those who are honest, in the end, have the most success on this site.

Comment: Just an advice. You can ignore it, or I to some extent pointed out why here are comments, suspicion, whatever. I didn't say anyone should hide anything, by the way, **I suggest, and have suggested that any personal/unrelated information shouldn't be in a "question"**. Of course you can ask for advice in this site.

Comment: I didn't see any "hiding" words in my original comment, though.

Comment: @amWhy I re-edited my question again. I did not want to "hide the truth". I just wanted to avoid getting to many downvotes for that one sentence.

Comment: @amWhy If I've said something really wrong please tell. "Not healthy to listen to the advice of a user who encourages users to leave out relevant information, i.e., to encourage users to game this site." *Hey dude, OP had deleted his words before I submitted my first comment!!

Comment: KeJie  I can understand that.

Comment: @amWhy I guess I really don't get it. You say it should be a problem statement, but then say it isn't. Do you have an issue with this question, or not?

Answer (score 2):

See what happens if  $a>b.$

You should come up with a contradiction.

If you are familiar with $\epsilon$ proofs, pick an $\epsilon$ to make your case.

I recommend drawing a graph to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If you consider the sequence $\{b_n-a_n\}$, this sequence is convergent, and importantly non-negative for any $n$ by assumption, with some limit $L$. All you need is to disprove this limit $L\lt0$ by picking a suitable $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assume the opposite, $$A =\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n > \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = B$$ and use the definition of a limit. Try to "separate" $A$ from $B$.